# getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

getting the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' what should I do?this error making my head blow up

````
async def message(ctx, *, mymsg):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="زاجل")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'انتظر قليلا وسيتم نشر  رسالتك <a:Aonigif2:780891217549328425> {ctx.message.author.mention}', delete_after=5)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await ctx.message.author.remove_roles(role)
    user = client.get_user(732195349661351987)
    await user.send(f'{mymsg}')```
````

Comment: `user` is `None`.  Which means that `client.get_user(...)` is returning `None`.  Maybe that user doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You require the `Members Intent`

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. Since you are developing your bot you might want to enable Presence intent as well to save you time later.

You will then have to edit your bot variable like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

Comment: @OtakuXD make sure the user shares a server with you