# Bot not detecting server members (Discord.py)

Tags: command, discord.py, member, mention

I have a command that I made to choose a random member for the server, but for some reason, whenever I run it, it only mentions itself.. As if it cannot detect that there are other members in the server besides itself. Here is the code:
ok

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['%', "v", "V"],
                      case_insensitive=True,
                      help_command=None)


intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Online! ;)')

    servers = len(client.guilds)
    members = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        members += guild.member_count - 1

    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(
        type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name=f'{servers} servers and {members} members | %help'))

@client.command()
async def choosemem(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(guild.members).mention} has been chosen")
```

This Is the full code, including the status, and the intents.

Comment: Make sure you have the Members intent enabled both in your code and in the developer portal.

Comment: Take a look at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67651195/getting-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send)

Comment: No, I checked the developer portal and added the intents code to my bot, but it still isn't detecting any other server members.

Comment: Send you full code with client definition please

Comment: I edited the code with the full thing, including status, and enabling intents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the intents value in client= commands.Bot as well

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['%', "v", "V"],
                      case_insensitive=True,
                      help_command=None,
                      intents = intents)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. It is still returning the bot itself.

Edit: I went back to the dev portal and enabled all intents. Now it works, thanks.
How can I mark this question as answered?